# Missing Gateway in Azure Classic Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm

Our Gateway in our Virtual Network (classic) seems to have disappeared.

[image]

There is also GatewaySubnet defined as in below....

[image]

, so when I attempt to re-create the gateway it looks like this..

[image]

Notice how in the above screenshot the subnet name appears grayed out. When I try to enter the address range for the "Gateway Subnet" from the 2nd screenshot, it is rejected, because the range is already in use. I tried to delete the "Gateway Subnet" and re-create it, but that did not work either..

Somethings seems corrupted here.. any idea what is going on?

Comment: I would suggest you open a support ticket with MSFT to have this looked into further. There is no reason a gateway would disappear unless someone deleted it. Had to tell what is going on without actually digging into your environment and seeing what is going on.

Comment: i'm pretty sure gateway subnet has to be called `gatewaysubnet`, so that is hardly a problem. not sure about CIDR block, try another CIDR block. as for it being randomly deleted, thats a bug if that happened. but you can take a look at activity logs for the resource group and determine if somebody tampered with it